# Why is this line of code running?

Tags: java, object

```
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer> ();
list.add(6);
list.add(1);
list.add(8);

int len = list.size();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    list.add(i+1, new Integer(i));
    System.out.println(list + "Iteration: " + i);
    Object x = list.set(i, new Integer(i+2));
}

System.out.println(list);
  }
```

Why does this code work? It turns the arraylist into:

[6, 0, 1, 8]Iteration: 0

[2, 0, 1, 1, 8]Iteration: 1

[2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 8]Iteration: 2

[2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 8]

But I'm not sure why this line compiles:

```
 Object x = list.set(i, new Integer(i+2));
```

Isn't it assigning an object to a method that doesn't return anything?

Comment: Are you saying that list.set(i, new Integer(i+2)); shouldn't do anything? I'm confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`set` method in `List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set-int-E-) returns what was previously at that position.

> Returns:
>
> the element previously at the specified position

That is why it compiles.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Official Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) the return element is the element previously at that position.

It doesn't return void.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt....

```
     System.out.println(x.toString() + " x: " +i);
```

throw that in after your Object assignment and it will show you the contents of x. If you run that you will get the following output:

```
 [6, 0, 1, 8]Iteration 0
 6 x:0
 [2, 0, 1, 1, 8]Iteration 1
 0 x:1
 [2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 8]Iteration 2
 1 x:2
 [2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 8]
```

From this you can see what is being returned from the list.set() method each iteration. The first time it returns the first element of the list, then the list prints showing that the first element has changed. The next iteration returns the second element and then prints the list with the second element replaced. The same happens with the next iteration.